UtilGetPpid:1293 Failed to parse
I'm getting this error when a try to build my app from my dockerfile:
8.497 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/4.2.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(75,5): error : <3>WSL (229) ERROR: UtilGetPpid:1293: Failed to parse: /proc/1/stat, content: 1 (sh) S 0 1 1 0 -1 4194560 641 0 31 0 1 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 32748 2637824 223 18446744073709551615 94865649782784 94865649859513 140725112987680 0 0 0 0 0 65538 1 0 0 17 6 0 0 0 0 0 94865649888816 94865649893952 94865683214336 140725112995313 140725112995398 140725112995398 140725112995824 0 [/src/net8.0/Jaimito.Utils/Jaimito.Utils.csproj]

I didn't really understand why the failure happened in this specific project within the solution, I did some research, but it didn't result in anything satisfactory, has anyone dealt with this type of problem with the Docker build?
PS.: it happens on the line RUN dotnet build "./Jaimito.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
I would appreciate any help.
